# Excel 2016 - Paste option to keep source formatting is not available

Tags: excel, formatting, copy-paste, vba

For some reason, my colleague has Excel 2016 and has the Paste option to keep source formatting. Right click on Mouse > Paste Options > Keep Source Formatting (K)

I have the exact same version of Excel 2016 - Office Professional Plus 2016 and we are pasting the exact same data, but I don't have the option to keep the source formatting, only to paste as text or a bitmap.

All my browser windows are closed.

Anyone else experienced the same?

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Paste Special](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Paste-Special-e03db6c7-8295-4529-957d-16ac8a778719)

Turn on the Paste Options button

The Paste Options button is turned on by default. If you don't see the button, it might be turned off. Follow these steps to turn it on.

In Word 2010, 2013, or 2016, click File > Options > Advanced.

In Word 2007, click the Microsoft Office Button  Office button image , and then click Word Options > Advanced.

In the Cut, copy, and paste section, select the Show Paste Options button when content is pasted check box.

Click OK.